# addthis share link not working in firefox and ie

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, addthis

addthis sharelink code not working in firefox and IE but working in chrome.

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit" pi:pinit:layout="horizontal"></a>
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4f323f450fe1cfc4"></script>
```

link to application is a www.sagarmahajan.com/demo/bmnet/products/product_details/9

Answer (score 0):

Loading in just fine here in IE9 (win7), IE11 (Win 8.1) and in Firefox (latest) on both operating systems.
Also good on my mac.

What behaviour were you seeing?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Please delete this post and repost as a comment.

Comment: i was seeing nothing but i gone through [post](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/5237416-addthis-sharing-menu-not-working-on-firefox-26-wordpress-3-8) and disabled antivirus addon from firefox and IR which used to prevent it. now i can see share buttons

Comment: Glad you sorted it - likely your anti virus blocking iframes / script injecting code to the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I gone through [post](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/5237416-addthis-sharing-menu-not-working-on-firefox-26-wordpress-3-8) and they have told to check the addons in firefox which may clean links.

Now I  disabled avast antivirus addon from firefox and IR which used to prevent it. now i can see share buttons.